# Download third party application through your application in iphone

Tags: ios4, ipad

I have some queries for iPhone
1) Can I  download third party application through my current application in iphone?

2) Can I get a notification if any application from iTunes gets installed on device? If there is any error while downloading the application from iTunes, Can I get notification for this also?

3) Can I come to know which applications are installed in iphone through my application?

Regards,
VM

Answer (score 0):

No to all 3 questions I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I download third party application through my current application in iphone

You can take iTunes URL for the application which you want to download and open it in safari which will launch the AppStore for you and user can download application from there.

For 2nd and 3rd question its not possible.